# How do I continue after the mainloop() in Tkinter?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I am making a Non-malicious Twitch TV bot that runs a few commands in chat. I have been using the bot for 2 months and decided to create a small GUI for basic changes to variables whilst it is running. Both the GUI and the Bot work fine separately but I am having issues making them work together.

I have used `Tkinter` to create the GUI and it requires a Loop to make the window remain open. This loop therefore stops the rest of the code continuing on and launching the bot. I need to work out how to keep the loop running but also continuing on to the rest of the Bot and run that behind the GUI.

This is the start of the Bot where it launches the GUI;

```
app = Geekster_Bot_GUI(None)
app.title('Geekster_Bot')
app.geometry('450x100')
app.mainloop()
```

It then continues to the bot connecting to the IRC.

How do I continue after the `mainloop()`?

Comment: How about, have the bot connect to IRC, and _then_ you call mainloop?

Comment: The bot itself also has a loop so either way i need to get round the loop

Comment: If the bot has an indefinite loop as well as your application you'll probably want the bot to run in the background (of sorts). To do this you'll want to use the Python threading package. This way you can set the bot to run in its own thread and then call the app.mainloop()

Comment: @Bob Thanks very much! I had a feeling it was threading! Any tips on threading them? Never done it before

Comment: See this example: http://code.activestate.com/recipes/82965-threads-tkinter-and-asynchronous-io/, it's old but still very sound.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [threading](https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html) or [multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html). Simple example:

```
import Tkinter
import threading

def create_frame():
    MessFrame = Tkinter.Tk()
    MessFrame.geometry('800x400+200+200')
    MessFrame.title('Main Frame')
    Framelabel = Tkinter.Label(MessFrame, text='Text Here', fg= 'red')
    Framelabel.place(x=10,y=10)
    MessFrame.mainloop()


t1 = threading.Thread(target=create_frame)
t1.start()

#continue
print 1234
```

But...it's generally best to keep the GUI in the main thread.