# Continuous Non-updating Loop

Tags: loops, methods, tkinter

I am no longer "new" to Python, but am now moving into unchartered territory.
Recently I was dissecting some logic circuit code found [here](http://www.openbookproject.net/courses/python4fun/logic.html). I learned a lot about the practical use of inheritance from this code. Good stuff.

Not much happens in this code until one changes the inputs on a gate, so the interpreter must be used to manipulate the inputs. I got tired of using the interpreter, and so I investigated ways to create a continuous loop that would not rerun the initial code.

I found that Tkinter uses a continuous loop that I could then interrupt with the "after" method to update some of the parameters of the code currently running.

That works well, however I am curious as to whether there is another and/or better way. Anyone know of one or the other?

Some of the code:

```
tk_TkGUI = Tk()
f_AndTest() ## Initialize the 'And' gate
tk_TkGUI.after(1000, f_ChangeAnInput) ## Invokes Tk 'after' method to update an input
tk_TkGUI.mainloop() ## Must be used in Windows with Tkinter

def f_ChangeAnInput():
    A1.B.set(0) ## Change A1.B from 1 to 0
```

Comment: Could [multithreading](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_multithreading.htm) be something for you?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yes. I investigated that initally, but many were saying "Beware," so I kept looking and found the Tkinter 'way.' Later I found [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24038772/continue-code-after-loop-continues) which may 'baby-step' me into threading and assist with this.

Comment: After more research into "threading" I still like this Tkinter loop "way." The problem with threading is that multiple and independent loops/threads are created. Using the Tkinter "way" I am able to have just the one loop going that I then interrupt occasionally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a window, using Tkinter in this way is perfectly fine.

By the way, `after` doesn't interrupt the loop as you described it. The main loop simply loops over a queue of events and processes them in order. When it reaches the end it waits for more events. Much like when you press a key or move the mouse, `after` merely puts something in the queue to be processed later. It really is as simple as that.

Answer (score 0):

you could use threading.

```
import thread
def blaH:
    #All your code that isn't related to your tkinter stuffs in here
thread.start_new_thread(blaH,())
```

the only thing is that you need new ways of both threads to talk to each other, such as [global variables](http://www.python-course.eu/global_vs_local_variables.php).